# PayPal Payments Standard custom HTML form; How does PayPal know who is submitting?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to get this form to initiate a donation using PayPal Payments Standard...

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
  <input type="text" name="amount"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="OrganizationXYZ Donation">
  <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://www.OrganizationXYZ.org/images/logo.gif">
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">  
</form>
```

This seems like it should work according to PayPal's [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics), but it doesn't. Instead I get this error:

**"We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com."**

This error doesn't make any sense because you do not supply an email address in these forms. Yet it seems to me that my form needs to post *some* kind of identification- otherwise how would PayPal know which account is receiving the donation? Unless I register a domain vai my PayPal account settings, but there is no place to do that either.

Does anybody have experience with setting this up?

Comment: Check out here simple paypal form, It may useful:  https://www.sanwebcorner.com/2020/02/simple-html-paypal-integration-form.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned, it need some sort of identifier of the recipient.
What you need to add is the 'business' parameter. That's all.

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your secure merchant account ID / email here">
```

Answer (score 7):

You must to have a merchant account.
You can see a tutorial here:
 http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/833/cpsid_83331.html

try this code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <select name="amount">
    <option value="3.99">6 Months ($3.99)</option>
    <option value="5.99">12 Months ($5.99)</option>

    </select>
    <br>
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD">
    <input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
    <input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00">
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="urlOnValidPayment">
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="UrlOnCancelPayment">
    <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="URLForValidationPayement">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
    <input name="business" type="hidden" value="your e-mail">
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="name of the object">
    <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="EN">
    <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input name="custom" type="hidden" value="custom data">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/CH/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

for me it's work

Comment: We have a business account with a confirmed email which allows to use Payments Standard. PayPal generated donation forms work fine, it's just the custom ones that don't.

Comment: Creates the same error. How would PayPal know, based on this form, who is submitting a payment?

Comment: By the input "custom" and the user have to connect him before the payment. Can you try with the sandbox version of paypal ? [https://developer.paypal.com/](https://developer.paypal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

¿Are you just generating the payment buton yourself?

I must recommend you to login to your PayPal account, go to this part of the menu:

Merchant Services -> Key Features -> Buy now Button

Then choose the button type I guess you want a Donate button.

Then configure the overall button settings, I must recommend to save the button in paypal servers.

Finally choose Create Button

This will give you the right HTML code. This is a sample donate button HTML.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR_BUSINESS_ID">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="myorgname">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="donateid">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom_variable1" value="val1">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom_variable2" value="val2">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm creating the form myself. I have some domain-specific logic to calculate donation amount which the PayPal-generated buttons can't handle.

Comment: @Thomas then yes, you need more params on your button. I'm pasting a sample generated button code so you can use this as example. You can also call the API so paypal can generate the button with the exact amount you need to charge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
```

Paypal's image value in Encrypted Payment System (WPS - EPS) for "cmd" is "_s-xclick"
So use it as below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
```