# PayPal encrypted button email address error

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am encrypting a PayPal button for on of our web sites and I've converted some sample code over to C# from Java and when I use the code on our test site we are getting the following error from PayPal:

[The PayPal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K3tV.png)

Our code is:

```
string data = "our hosted button parameters";
AsymmetricKeyParameter myKey = readPrivateKey("mma-prvkey.pem");

//2. Read certificate X509
X509Certificate myCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("mma-pubcert.pem");
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(myCert);

//3. Read paypal cert
X509Certificate orgPaypalCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("paypal_cert.pem");
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate paypalCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(orgPaypalCert);

//4. Create generator
CmsSignedDataGenerator signedGenerator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
signedGenerator.AddSigner(myKey, bcCert, CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha1);

//5. Add cert store
ArrayList certList = new ArrayList();
certList.Add(bcCert);
IX509Store certStore = X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", new 
X509CollectionStoreParameters(certList));
signedGenerator.AddCertificates(certStore);
//Create data byte array
byte[] dataToBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
CmsProcessableByteArray cmsByteArray = new CmsProcessableByteArray(dataToBytes);

CmsSignedData signedData = signedGenerator.Generate(cmsByteArray, true);
byte[] signed = signedData.GetEncoded();

//6. Create Envelope with PayPal cert
CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator envGenerator = new CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator();
envGenerator.AddKeyTransRecipient(paypalCert);
CmsEnvelopedData envData = envGenerator.Generate(new CmsProcessableByteArray(signed), CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.DesEde3Cbc);

byte[] pkcs7Bytes = envData.GetEncoded();

//7. return encryptedfile
var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(pkcs7Bytes);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\signed.xml", base64Data);
```

What I don't understand is how PayPal knows who we are?  Our certificate id is in the encrypted data and there doesn't seem to be any identifying markers for us in the html:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHA6CAMIACAQAxggE6MIIBNgIBADCBnjC_redacted_data_AAAAAAAAAAAAA=">
    <input id="confirmNextGold" name="submit" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Confirm Upgrade" class="widerButton" />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do unencrypted buttons work? As maybe it is just a problem with your email address on the account.

Comment: Yes they work fine unencrypted.

Comment: There is a similiar question here but no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672943/invalid-email-address-error-when-trying-to-integrate-a-donations-button?noredirect=1&lq=1